# Unification with mystery variable

Tags: haskell, ghc

In the following snippet, I incorrectly tagged `entailFunctor` with `t` *and* `r`, instead of just `t`. As a result, when I try to use it, I need both `t` and `r` in scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Tagged
import Data.Proxy

entailFunctor  :: Tagged (t r) (() :- (Functor t))
entailFunctor = undefined

newtype Foo t r = Foo (t r)

instance Functor (Foo t) where
  fmap f (Foo a) = Foo $ fmap f a \\ proxy entailFunctor (Proxy::Proxy (t r))
```

That's a problem because (at least the way I wrote my `Functor` instance) `r` **isn't** in scope. Yet this compiles with GHC 8.0.1! Is this a bug, and if not, to what does the type variable `r` refer in the definition of `fmap`?

Comment: The usual, I'd assume: `forall r. Proxy (t r)`

Comment: So that works  because `r` doesn't need to unify with anything, and also doesn't have any constraints?